# Apache Force WWW & SSL & Support other Subdomains

Tags: ssl, apache-2.4, virtualhost, subdomain

I have been searching for hours and have come very close but not quite complete.

I have this currently as my Virtual Hosts file.

```
ServerName example.com
DocumentRoot /mnt/WWW
ServerAdmin support@krc.com.au
RemoteIPHeader X-Forwarded-For

# Needed before any rewriting
RewriteEngine On

### Built using the .htaccess 301 Redirect Generator from Web Site Advantage
### https://websiteadvantage.com.au/HtAccess-301-Redirect-Generator
### Place after 'RewriteEngine On' and before any CMS specific rewrite rules

# Redirect HTTP with www to HTTPS with www
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
# Redirect HTTP without www to HTTPS with www
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule .* https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
# Redirect HTTPS without www to HTTPS with www
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule .* https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

## 301 Redirects

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

<VirtualHost *:443>
    DocumentRoot "/mnt/WWW/www.example.com"
    ServerName www.example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com

    <Directory />
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride all
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /root/ssl/example.com.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /root/ssl/private.key
    SSLCACertificateFile /root/ssl/intermediateCA.crt
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    # NAS
    ServerName nas.example.com
    ServerAlias nas.example.com

    ProxyPass / http://10.0.28.1:5000/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://10.0.28.1:5000/

    SSLEngine on
    SSLProxyEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /root/ssl/example.com.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /root/ssl/private.key
    SSLCACertificateFile /root/ssl/intermediateCA.crt
</VirtualHost>
```

Now here is what I am trying to do. I have the root folder /mnt/WWW.

I want ALL HTTP request to automatically switch to https. I then want all non-www subdomains to stay as the subdomain, but force example.com to always be www.example.com

Currently, the above works as follows:

```
http://example.com      -> https://www.example.com     = Correct
http://www.example.com  -> https://www.example.com     = Correct
http://sub.example.com  -> https://www.sub.example.com = Wrong - Should be https://sub.example.com
https://example.com     -> https://example.com         = Wrong - Should be https://www.example.com
https://www.example.com -> https://www.example.com     = Correct
https://sub.example.com -> https://sub.example.com     = Correct
```

I can get most of these things to work at some point or another but am yet to get it ALL to work at the same time under the one config.

Also, am trying to simplify the code by placing common settings as defaults. Is there another way to minimise duplicate lines that are common to all Reverse Proxies and such?

Answer (score 0):

I changed the Rewrite to the Following:

```
#Force WWW Subdomain
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^[0-9a-zA-Z-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,}$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}:443$1 [R=301,L]

#Force SSL
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}:443$1 [R,L]
```

Now everything works.